# Recursion not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone help me get this small piece of code to call itself recursively. It only fires once then stops and it doesn't do any animation. What I'm trying to do is animate a border on an image element recursively after the person has shared their geo-location. This code is inside `document.ready`.

```
(function pulse(){
    console.log('hello world');
    $('.contacts-list li.closest img')
        .delay(1000)
        .animate({ 'border-color': 'transparent'}, 100)
        .delay(500)
        .animate({ 'border-color': 'rgb(147, 190, 104)'}, 100, pulse);
})();
```

Comment: recursion in javascript isn't going to give you the results you require. look up setTimeout and setInterval, or if you want to trigger something in response to an event wire-up an eventhandler

Comment: Your function is actually fine, it calls itself again, again and again. Which is probably not the best way to do it. But afaik, without using a plugin, `$.animate` will not animate the `border-color` property, that's why you are not seeing a result. Have you tried using a CSS3 animation instead? Just apply it via a class to your `img` element when needed.

Comment: actually when you console.log out the hello world it only consoles it out once

Comment: @KDM Keep in mind, that some consoles will group identical consecutive logs. But your code actually works, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/LTvbL/ However, as christian314159 mentioned correctly, the border-color attribute will not be animated.

Comment: And here is another example, showing that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/LTvbL/1/. I assume plain jQuery cannot animate colors.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
(function pulse(){
    console.log('hello world');
    $('.contacts-list li.closest img')
        .delay(1000)
        .animate({ 'border-color': 'transparent'}, 100)
        .delay(500)
        .animate({ 'border-color': 'rgb(147, 190, 104)'}, 100, function() 
        {
            pulse();
        });
})();
```

Comment: it only executes once then it stops

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Code without an **explanation** is not very helpful in most cases.

Comment: FYI, `function() { pulse(); }` is equivalent to `pulse`. If that's the only change you made, then it won't solve the problem (whatever it is).